# CloudAMQP & Android

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq, real-time, cloudamqp

I am planning to use CloudAMQP on an Android app.
My query is does AMQP work over sockets on Android?

I am concerned since it's going to be a real time app and there will be lot of message passing in a session and I can't batch those messages.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Query is does cloudAMQP android client work over sockets or always alive TCP connection?